# Multiple json objects extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

From my database i get multiple json object, the json object looks as follows.

```
[{"id":"90","email_address":test@test.com"},{"id":"92","email_address":test2@test2.com"}]
```

Now i want to make a treeview in Extjs that gives this data in so called nodes. But how do i read multiple object in a treestore? I tried to read one object in a store but that did not work. On the internet i found no solutions so far(only nested json objects(which is not the case here).

Wrapping it up: the problem is that my store won't read multiple objects.

The object are dynamicly loaded(so for instance the json can have 1000 objects)

Comment: You need to insert both of them into Root Node created by yourself

Comment: The result objects are dynamic. So for instance it can be 4 or even 100 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your data in the middleware layer of your app (on the server-side) into hierarchical data presentation. Also you'll need to add "leaf" attribute to tree leaves. Check fiddle for example

```
"root": {
            "expanded": true,
            "children": [
             {
                "id": "90",
                "text": "test@test.com", 
                "leaf":true
             },
              {
                "id" : "92",
                "text":"test2@test2.com",
                "leaf": true
             }]
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pura0xza/

Comment: So the returning json must be 1 object? I don't think that is possible because the objects represent multiple rows/records from the database(postgres)

Comment: The tree, by concept, exists for working with hierarchical data. If you need to represent just plain data, with no parent-child relationship - you sould use list, not a tree

Comment: @РоманГуйван is correct. You have to define a 'root' node and place all the items under its children as an array. Set 'rootVisible' to false if you do not want to show the 'root' node.